# error when displaying more details in plotly tooltip

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

Im trying to display more data on hoover over a point, than default point coordinates. 
It works when I display only one extra information for example:

```
 output$myplot <- renderPlotly({
    if (is.null(filtered())) {
      return()
    }
    ggplot(filtered(), aes_string(x=input$xvar, y=input$yvar, text=filtered()$Ep.name)) +
      geom_point()
  })
```

Works just fine and I get what I want to achieve (which is the data that i pass to `text` variable. But when I tried passing more variables, using `paste`:

```
 ggplot(filtered(), aes_string(x=input$xvar, y=input$yvar, text=paste("name: ",filtered()$Ep.name, "season: ", filtered()$Season, "number: ", filtered()$Ep.Number))) +
      geom_point()
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: Error in parse: <text>:1:12: unexpected symbol
1: name:  The Kingsroad
```

Which means there is something wrong with the value when it is pasted.
However I have no idea how to inlcude all three variables from the filtered() dataframe onto aes_string so that they are all displayed in the tooltip.
Anyone has idea how to solve this?

EDIT: Here is code that allows you to reproduce the error, along with the sample of the dataset im using for this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)


shows <- read.csv("finalR1.csv", header=TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(h1("Plot"),
             plotlyOutput("myplot"),
             hr()),
    tabPanel(h1("Table"), tableOutput("results"))
  ),

  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           h4("Episode explorer"), 
           sliderInput("voteInput", "Votes", min = 0, max = 155000, value = c(2500, 40000)),
           br(),
           sliderInput("lenInput", "Length", min = 0, max = 110, value = c(0, 60)),
           br(),
           uiOutput("ratingOutput")

    ),

   column(4,offset = 0.5,
          h4('Axis display options'),
          selectInput('xvar', 'X', choice=c("Length", "Ep.Rating", "Votes", "Year"), selected="Ep.Rating"),
          selectInput('yvar', 'Y', choice=c("Length", "Ep.Rating", "Votes", "Year"), selected="Votes")
          ))

)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ratingOutput <- renderUI({
    selectInput("ratingInput", "Ratings",
                c("All", as.character(sort(unique(shows$TV.Rating)))),
                selected = "All")
  })


  filtered<-reactive({
    if (is.null(input$ratingInput)) {
      return(NULL)
    }

    shows %>%
    filter(Votes >= input$voteInput[1],
           Votes <= input$voteInput[2],
           Length >= input$lenInput[1],
           Length <= input$lenInput[2],
           if (input$ratingInput != "All") {
             TV.Rating == input$ratingInput
           } else TRUE

    )

  })

  output$myplot <- renderPlotly({
    if (is.null(filtered())) {
      return()
    }
    ggplot(filtered(), aes_string(x=input$xvar, y=input$yvar, text=paste("name: ",filtered()$Ep.name, "season: ", filtered()$Season, "number: ", filtered()$Ep.Number))) +
      geom_point()
  })

  output$results <- renderTable({
    filtered()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15ZqzY_msBBlBnrrqsqeagZSpJxifKKjM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share the full code so we can run it?

Comment: My code is up, as well as dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this:

```
  output$myplot <- renderPlotly({
    if (is.null(filtered())) {
      return()
    }

  a <- ggplot(filtered(), aes_string(x=input$xvar, y=input$yvar))  +
      geom_point(aes(text=paste('name:',filtered()$Ep.name, '<br>season:', filtered()$Season, '<br>number:', filtered()$Ep.Number)))

  ggplotly(a, tooltip = c("x", "y", "text"))

  })
```

Comment: It seems to work as I wanted, however now the point values that were displayed by default (coordinates) are no more being shown. Is there a way to keep them there as well? I dont want to hardcode them as the X and Y variables change

Comment: @Alex T. Please see edit. You can simply use this: `ggplotly(a, tooltip = c("x", "y", "text"))`.